# Can grunt-wiredep conditionally load different Bower scripts in different pages?

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-wiredep

I am new to Bower/Grunt, so excuse me if this seems a silly question.

Before I was using Liquid Templating to insert blocks of scripts and styles in different pages. The links to those scripts and styles were hardcoded manually. Different pages had different scripts/styles added in an as-needed basis to reduce load time.

I recently learned about Wiredep and that it can automatically inject bower components to the markup. Only one problem I am facing is that it injects ALL the bower components in ALL the pages. I am afraid that will significantly hamper the initial load time (I have many different scripts) I only need it to inject some components in some pages.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Bower/Grunt also.
I came across [grunt-wiredep on multiple files with different dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342126/grunt-wiredep-on-multiple-files-with-different-dependencies)

My current thinking is that because bower/grunt will combine these dependencies into a single file, the advantage is in minimising the repeated requests for different combinations of dependencies and rather providing a single larger file that includes all dependencies. With this cached it should minimise the number of requests even if many of the dependencies are not utilised often.

My guess is that if there were significant differences that you would create a different grunt/bower configuration for that part of your application which would group the related parts only.

If I am mistaken I would love to hear from someone with more experience.

Comment: Does wiredep concatenate and uglify the dependencies to a single file? I'm using grunt wiredep, but it will just add the dependent js and css to the main html file. Am I missing something?