# grunt-wiredep on multiple files with different dependencies

Tags: gruntjs, bower, wiredep, grunt-wiredep

The current project structure is somewhat like this:

```
-index.html
|
-bower.json
|
+-bower_components
```

The proposed project structure will add a few more static html files in the project root. Till now I have been managing all the frontend dependencies in bower.json and had it automatically included in index.html using the grunt-wiredep task. But with new files getting added, each file will have different set of dependencies.

```
-index.html
|
-file-with-some-other-bower-dependency.html
|
-bower.json
|
+bower_components
```

What would be an efficient way of managing these files with different bower dependencies?

Comment: grunt-wiredep add reference to the files listed in the `main` property of a package. It scans the files that you mention and add these dependencies automatically. I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible

Comment: Is project in angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

You can do two different task, each with their own dependencies (bowerJson) :

```
  grunt.initConfig({
wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: 'index.html',
    "bowerJson":{
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery":"=2.1.3",
          ...
      }
    }

  },
  app2: {
    src: 'file-with-some-other-bower-dependency.html',
    "bowerJson": {
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
        ...
      }
    }
  }}
```